# Magento 1.9 - same local IP for all customers online

Tags: php, magento, payment, magento-1.9

Our Magento 1.9.0.1 admin panel shows 127.0.0.1 for all online customer instead of the real IP address. Due to the wrong IP I can not use an important payment gateway. Does anyone know what can be wrong and what can I check? The Extension support from Klarna Payment tells us, that anything in magento is configured wrong. We update our Store from 1.5 to 1.9. All other parts work fine.
Thanks in advance. 
Best
Jun

Comment: Are you using Varnish on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any layer between user and the app-server for ex. Varnish? If yes this is probably the issue - because the appservers receives the IP of the service and not the original user.

Do a `var_dump($_SERVER);` and normally U use the `REMOTE_ADDR` key to get the users IP but if there is an additional service in the middle this value will probably be the IP of the service, look for  the key `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and verify whether it is the IP you need.

Comment: Thanks, we tested a Varnish extension -Turpentine. Deactivated this at the moment cause having some trouble with ist. I am not shure in the ip Problem also was before or not. With deactivated extension the Problem Is the same. Maybe delete all folders and Data from turpentine?

Comment: if you use varnish there always will be such problem - you have to configure varnish to forward the original IP and then use the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR instead of REMOTE_ADDR - but it is worth saying that the value could be manipulated;)